# How do I distinguish between download tasks in a background session?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm currently trying to do some debugging on an issue with my background download tasks mysteriously failing during network switches, and found some documentation suggesting that I should be putting multiple tasks into a single background session.

Once you've added more than one background task to a session, how do you determine which task you're looking at?  To give an example, lets assume I've downloaded a list of data-entries from the server, and I'm using background session handling to download their associated thumbnails.

When a background task finishes, the session delegate receives a callback to `urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)`.

I can set an identifier on the background session (in fact, you have to); how do you do so with the individual tasks? I want to be able to re-associate a specific task with a specific data object after the app restarts, but there doesn't seem to be any mechanism for doing so.

Am I misunderstanding or missing something in the docs?

Comment: Have you looked as the `taskDescription` and `taskIdentifier` properties?

Comment: @rmaddy that would be the item I'm missing from the docs, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURLSessionDownloadTask` is a subclass of `NSURLSessionTask`, which has a `taskIdentifier` property that you can set. Therefore, an `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` object *is an* instance of `NSURLSessionTask`, and you can set it's `taskIdentifier` property.

Comment: taskIdentifier is a get-only property, you can't set it.

But you can 'get' it and store it on task creation.

Comment: You can use taskDescription instead if you need to be able to set it. I don't know if the OS will recreate it with the proper description after termination, but I'm going to try and find out.